# Create custom nested 2 horizontal listviews in android like Google Play

Tags: android, listview, layout

I want to make an app that have to `listview`s (or `RecycleView`) that second is inside first list view and both are horizontal. I in fact want to make a layout like Google Play apps list.
besides I want my first listview have Title and More text for more apps on that category.
How can I do these like following figure:

[image]

Comment: Why not use two `RecyclerViews`and configure them to use the [`LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) As for the titles, just add two `TextViews` above the respective `RecyclerViews`.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Yes you are right. but I cant implement this. I find a good tutorial for that. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I find a tutorial myself. It is perfect:

[horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical](http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html)